# Can a tree be used to create a stack?

Tags: data-structures, trees, stack

I'm aware that linked lists, sets and arrays can be used to create stacks by themselves. The theory behind it is this

`linked-list`: In some languages, a linked-list is substitutable for an array. Stacks are First In First Out operations.

`array`: The `push` and `pop` methods invoke a stack like behavior.

`set`: A set is exactly the same as an array, except it does not feature duplicate elements.

I'm struggling to find a way that a tree can be used to create a stack

Comment: How about a tree that's degenerated to a linked-list?

Comment: A set is *not* exactly the same as an array except without duplicates.  An array is indexed in order, while a set is *explicitly unordered.*

Comment: A tree with terminators on all right hand nodes would work as a stack as you'd have a single linear list of data down the left hand nodes.

Comment: @MasonWheeler: "a set is explicitly unordered". Not in maths, it sure ain't, eg integers are a set and they were pretty well ordered last time I looked.

Comment: A set is not identical to an array without dupes.  Iterating over an array is guaranteed to return the objects in the order you put them in the first place.  Iterating over a set happens in some other order, defined by the implementation.  (for example Python sets are iterated in no particular order, while C++ sets are iterated in ascending order).

Comment: @DavidArno: Even in maths, there is no concept of "the first element of a set". That is what is meant with sets being unordered.

Comment: @DavidArno: The integers have an order, but that has nothing to do with their being a set.

Comment: @BartvanIngenSchenau, the first element of the totally ordered set of positive, non-zero, single digit numbers is 1. The last is 9. The fact that the set has a finite number of elements, that all exhibit transitivity, comparability etc, means that they have an order, a start and and end, ie it's a totally ordered set. Not all sets are totally ordered, eg the set of all integers has no first element and so is only partially ordered. Some sets, eg { cow, dog, sheep } are unordered.

Comment: @MichaelShaw, you may find it useful to read up on set theory, eg the "well ordering principle" that states that any non empty positive integer set has a smallest (first) member. Sets can have order. Not all do, but some do.

Comment: @DavidArno: Having an order is not a property of a set.  Sets contain members.  You can think of them as a function that takes a possible member and returns true if the set contains it or false if it doesn't.  That has nothing to do with order.

Answer (score 3):

Trivially.

Your stack object simply maintains a tree of ints.   The Push operation is identical to the insertion of an item in the tree whose key is one greater than the key in the current maximum.  That should be the key in the root note, and the new node becomes the new root.

The Pop operation is removal of the node with the greatest key (the root).

This approach should still work with self-balancing trees, though for those it will be slower (since the maximum key is no longer at the root and so accessing it takes O(ln N) rather than O(1)).

The contents of the stack locations would simply be additional content in the tree nodes.

Answer (score 0):

There is a good answer already given, but you could also implement a max-heap then insert an element with a priority equal to the number of elements currently in your heap.